# Accessing Oracle Synonyms using Entity Framework 6 code first

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, entity-framework-6

I am currently working on a project which will use Entity Framework 6.1.1 and an Oracle 11g database backend.  I will be accessing tables across multiple schemas some of which have foreign key relationships across schemas as well (look-up tables, enterprise data, etc...).

Traditionally we have used synonyms as a means of exposing these cross-schema tables to a particular login.  My question is... how can I map these synonyms in EF6 using code first mapping?  I have no problems mapping to tables directly within a single schema, but this of course won't be sufficient since my tables cross several schemas.  So far my code first mappings do not recognize synonyms.

Has anyone been able to do code-first mappings to Oracle synonyms?

Comment: Were you able to use EF code first with synonyms? I've got the same problem currently.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set the schema for the specific entities:

`modelBuilder.Entity<DATA>().ToTable("DATA", "schema");`

Or decorate the class:

`[Table("DATA", Schema="SCHEMA"]
    public class DATA{..}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the EF Fluent API to define the schema:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("MY_SCHEMA_NAME");
}
```

If you would like to use Oracle synonyms, you can remove the schema:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(string.Empty);
}
```

This would produce SQL containing `FROM "MY_TABLE"` instead of `FROM "dbo"."MY_TABLE"` or `FROM "MY_SCHEMA_NAME"."MY_TABLE"`

I'm using:

- EntityFramework 6.1.3
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 12.1.2400
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 12.1.2400